# Cannot call a Craft 3 module's action

Tags: php, module, controller, homestead, craftcms

I'm trying to setup a controller action that can be called by a cron job. I have a controller living inside `modules/chill/controllers/NotificationController` with the action `actionIndex` running in Homestead at `http://chill.test`.

When calling the url `http://chill.test/actions/chill/notifications/index` I get a native browser login screen. The controller extends `craft\web\Controller` and overrides $allowAnonymous.

The controller looks like this:

```php
<?php
namespace Chill\Controllers;

use Craft;
use craft\web\Controller;

class NotificationsController extends Controller
{
    protected $allowAnonymous = true;

    /*
     * Call via: http://chill.test/actions/chill/notifications/index
     */
    public function actionIndex(){

        Craft::$app->getDeprecator()->log("Chill", "Testing the error logging on index action", 'notifications.log');

        return 'Welcome to the NotificationsController actionIndex() method';
    }
}
```

Also calling the url via Paw with application/json setup in the headers I get the following 401-response:

```json
{
  "error": "Your request was made with invalid credentials."
}
```

Any ideas on how to bypass the login popup or am I setting this up wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I normally setup a Module and then register routes using Crafts Events

```php
private function _registerSiteRoutes()
{
     Event::on(UrlManager::class, UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES,
         function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
             $event->rules[] = [
                 'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                 'controller' => ['api/' => 'my-module/api/v1/base'],
                 'extraPatterns' => [
                      'GET notifications' => 'notifications',
                 ],
             ];
         }
     );
}
```